# Querying/importing millions of rows in R from MySQL

Tags: mysql, r, bigdata, dbi, rmysql

I am having performance issues. I have an indexed table of 3 millions rows, which will eventually get to 15 millions in MySQL.

When I run a simple query from R through dbi/RMySQL

`Select * from sales where transaction_year = 2022;`

So transaction_year is indexed among other columns. The table has 60 columns. it takes me a minute. My RAM is 16 gb with a i7 processor.

Are there ways to significantly reduce the downloading time to less than 10 seconds? Thank you.

Comment: Are you connected to a remote MySQL Server? Which drivers are you using? is it an ODBC connection? connection string? Fetch size parameter value? any code?

Comment: Actually this will also depend upon the further processing of data. If you are planning to manipulate it within a single dplyr pipe it will transform the MySQL query statement sent to the server thus affecting the time

Comment: Are there millions of rows in the resultset?  What will be done with such a large volume of data?

Comment: Yes the resultset is like 2 million rows.

Comment: Basically, I want to be able to download a very large resultset. 
The query itself on the mysql server is executed quite SLOWLY.

Comment: So I now realize the issue is not with R and RMySQL but with my database server itself.

Answer (score 0):

We really need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the important queries.  I'll assume you have

```
 CREATE TABLE stuff (
     id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
     transaction_year YEAR NOT NULL,
     ...
     PRIMARY KEY(id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

In that case, change the PK to these:

```
   PRIMARY KEY(transaction_year, id),  -- to significantly speed up that  query
   INDEX(id)    -- just to keep auto_inc happy
```

I don't know if this will hurt the performance of other queries; I really need to see more info.

If you really have `transaction_date DATE` not a `year` by itself, then

```
where transaction_year = 2022
```

needs to be

```
where transaction_year >= "2022-01-01"
  AND transaction_year  < "2022-01-01" + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

(And my indexing advice still applies.)

If you expect to purge old data after some number of years, then we can talk about Partitioning.  See [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)